# How to change a prompt to an input text and wait the user until send the code in firebase verifyPhoneNumber method?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on an angular project where user can Verify order by enter his phone number and get a Verification Code in his phone and then send it back with Firebase `verifyPhoneNumber` Method.
I want to change the code from getting the Verification Code of a prompt to an input shown after the user enter his number and click `send the code` button.

```
ngOnInit(){
...
firebase.auth().useDeviceLanguage();
this.windowRef = this.win.windowRef;
this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier.render();
this.provider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
}

sendLoginCode() {
    const appVerifier = this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier;
    const num = this.phoneNumber.e164;
    console.log(num);

    this.provider.verifyPhoneNumber(num, appVerifier)
      .then(verificationId => {
        var verificationCode = window.prompt('Please enter the verification code that was sent to your mobile device.');
        return firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId,
          verificationCode);
      })
      .then(phoneCredential => {
        console.log(phoneCredential);
        return firebase.auth().currentUser.updatePhoneNumber(phoneCredential);
      })
      .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
  }
```

I think this function need to be splited and It need to add a function to verify the verification code and execute the rest of the function.